# SQL replacing a subset with the values it is made up of

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(AnimalId varchar(5), BodyPartId varchar(5), Value decimal)
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT 'A', 'X', 50 union all
SELECT 'A', 'Y', 75 union all
SELECT 'A', 'B', 100 union all
SELECT 'B', 'K', 60 union all
SELECT 'B', 'J', 53
```

Animals are made up of body parts that have a certain value. Their body parts can also be other animals.

I need to be able to replace body parts that are other animals with the value of the other animals body parts.

Is it possible to do this in SQL?

To calculate it using the example above, I would find out which body parts are animals (B). Then for these animals I would work out the percentage that each body part makes up.

```
K divided by total of B: 60/113 = 0.53
J divided by total of B: 53/113 = 0.47
```

I would then multiply these values by B's total in A:

```
Ks percentage times 100: 0.53 * 100 = 53
Js percentage times 100: 0.47 * 100 = 47
```

So the final make up of animal A is:

```
X 50
Y 75
K 53
J 47
```

I'm struggling to find the percentage make up of each body part relative to the animal. 
I'm assuming animals can only be made up of other animals that are only made up of body parts - so I don't need a recursive solution (although that would be nice to see).

Comment: is this homework? Or are you starting a weird zoo?

Comment: no. im just not good at thinking of examples

Comment: Animals can have body parts made up of other animals?  Is someone a mad scientist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've put together a solution that seems to work, but it would be good to test it on more complex scenarios or know what types of scenarios may be involved, such as sub-sub-animals, or animals that are the sub of multiple parent animals, or duplicate body parts, etc.

First, calculate the percentages and totals for body parts that are part of an animal that is a sub-animal of a parent animal, and update back to the table with the new totals.  Also, update the parent animal to match the correct new parent animal:

```
-- update body parts of sub-animals to new value and parent animal
-- also set parent animal bodypartid to itself so it can be identified
with animalbodyparts as (
  select * from animals
  where bodypartid in (select animalid from animals)
), totals as (
  select a.animalid, sum(a.value) as subtotal
  from animals a
  group by a.animalid
), newtotals as (
  select ab.animalid as parentanimalid, t.animalid,
    p.bodypartid, p.value / t.subtotal as percentage,
    ab.value as newtotal, cast(p.value / t.subtotal * ab.value as integer) as newvalue
  from animalbodyparts ab
  join totals t on ab.bodypartid = t.animalid
  join animals p on t.animalid = p.animalid
)
update a
set
  a.animalid = 
    case
      when t.parentanimalid is null then a.animalid
      else t.parentanimalid
    end,
  a.bodypartid =
    case
      when t.animalid = a.bodypartid then t.parentanimalid
      else a.bodypartid
    end,
  a.value =
    case
      when t.newvalue is null then a.value
      else t.newvalue
    end
from animals a
left join newtotals t on a.bodypartid = t.bodypartid
  or t.animalid = a.bodypartid;
```

Also, I update the bodypartid to be the same as the parent animal when the bodypartid was a reference to a child animal as a body part.  This is because there is no other way to reference what body parts were once references to animals once I update the animalid of the sub-parts.  I update it to the same value so I can tell which ones need to be removed, since they now have matching bodypartid and animalid values:

```
--cleanup by removing the body parts that were sub-animals
delete from animals where animalid = bodypartid
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a5a0/39

NOTE: I get a final result of `46` for `J` because I'm rounding after the total calculation, whereas you are rounding the percentage first before calculating the new value.  That should be pretty trivial to change if necessary.  Note that with either method, there is no guarantee that the new values will total the original old total (i.e., that 47 + 53 = 100).  There are - rare - pathological scenarios (probably involving 3 or more body parts in the sub animal) where you'll end up with a slightly different total than the original even if you round first.

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution, and I'd never seen SQLfiddle before...Removed the casting to ints and ended up with 47